# VMWare virtual machine to real SO

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I have a virtual Debian installation with VMWare Player on Windows 7 x64..
Since i have made already some modifications, i want to 'copy' this installation inside a partition to have a real Debian installation with dual boot along Win 7

It is possible?

Comment: Nobody will recommend doing this, but yes its possible. It may or may not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am gonna Tell you the Simplest way, but other ways are also possible (I have listed them to the End)

**Requirements:**
You Should have Some space on you HDD to hold the image created (Later Explanation to it).
Clonezilla ISO file (download it from [clonezilla.org](http://clonezilla.org/))

**Procedure:**

> Attach your Physical Disk (or partition) to your Virtual Machine, For
>   that.. [image: 1] Then
>  [image: 2] Then
>  Make sure you select the
>   correct drive that you want to use for your physical disk(The one on
>   which to Restore VM to) and select the option Use entire disk(Or
>   partitions if you want to Restore to a partition)
>  [image: 3] Then
>   Name the File and Continue..
>  [image: 4]

Now

> Attach the Clonezilla ISO to the VM and Boot from it.
>   **(If you know how to use Clonezilla to Resote a local disk to disk then Do the same, else I am gonna Explain it Below)** 
> As it boots,
>   Select Clonezilla Live, then Select your Preferred language.
>  Then
>   Choose "Start Clonezilla" [image: 5] 
> Then Select "device-device"
>   option and continue [image: 6] 
> Then choose Beginner Mode and continue
>   [image: 7]  
> Then Select "disk_to_local_disk" [image: 8] 
> Then select
>   your Virtual Disk[image: 9]
>  Then at last Choose your Physical
>   disk[image: 10]

***NOW LASTLY YOU JUST NEED TO MODIFY THE BOOTLOADER*** (Which I cant Explain now)
This Process can be Explained at 
http://www.howtoforge.com/converting-a-vmware-image-to-a-physical-machine-p2

Other usefull Links:
http://www.vmware.com/support/v2p/index.html
http://www.acronis.com/articles/v2p/
http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/convert-use-your-physical-machine-in-vmware-virtualbox-virtual-pc/